# Relative paths not resolved in IIS5 same as IIS6

Tags: iis-6, windows-xp, relative-path, iis-5

I have a C# website which works fine in IIS6 & IIS7 on a company intranet but am now attempting to install the same website on a Windows XP box with IIS5 for a different part of the company intranet. The website content is fine but the css and menus are all broken, as some of the relative paths can't be found.

I am using some notation like this: `<img src="Images/a.gif"` which works fine, and some like this: `MasterPageFile="~/App_MasterPages/Default.master"` which also works fine, but the stuff like this: `@import "/App_Themes/Default.css"` and this: `src="../App_Scripts/stringformat.js"` is no good. In the code-behind `Request.ApplicationPath` is also missing the "/" off the end.

I tried unticking the "Enable Parent Path" in IIS and did an iisreset but it made no difference. I also tried installing IIS Developer Express, but that was confusing and sucked too much. I don't want to have to go through the whole application and change every relative path just to support IIS5 format, but is that my only option? (apart from upgrading Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that on IIS6 & 7 the application in question is being deployed into the site root and that on XP/IIS5.1 you've deployed this into a sub folder running as an IIS application.

You have two options:

1. Deploy the site into the IIS5.1 root (`c:\inetpub\wwwroot`).
2. Fix the absolute paths and make them application relative i.e. `@import /App_Themes`.
3. Persevere with IIS Developer Express, it's not that sucky.

Comment: Both sites are deployed into `inetpub\wwwroot` so that is not the issue. I'm not that keen on point 2 either as there are a lot of links to update, and could break it for IIS6/7? IIS Express was unintelligible and I can't see how to run a website the usual way. There were so many questions I had that wasn't answered by microsofts documentation. Do I have to uninstall IIS5 for example?

Comment: @jumpingjezza - You say "both sites"? Can you update your answer to give us some idea of your folder structure?

Comment: both sites meaning the same website set up on different servers in different intranets

Comment: no-one came up with a better idea, so I'll mark you correct for point 2: Find and fix ALL the path references